# Akka: dynamically add Actors to BroadcastRouter

Tags: java, events, akka, actor

What is the correct way to have a Broadcast actor dynamically add/remove routees over time?

Context of the problem:
An actor listens to price changes of a particular item, then it broadcasts to all other actors (routees) the price change and they act according to internal rules (for example if the price is X buy or sell).

I am new to Akka, but after reading through the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/) I believe I have figured out the components needed but if you feel my design or components used are incorrect please comment/answer.

I want to change from a fixed list of routees

```
        ActorRef actor1 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class));
        ActorRef actor2 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class));
        ActorRef actor3 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class));
        Iterable<ActorRef> routees = Arrays.asList(new ActorRef[] { actor1, actor2, actor3 });
        ActorRef actorBroadcastRouter1 = system.actorOf(new Props(TickerWatcherActor.class).withRouter(BroadcastRouter.create(routees)), "router1");
```

To something like a dynamically sized BroadcastRouter where actors are created after the BroadcastRouter is up and running

```
        int lowerBound = 1;
        int upperBound = 10000;
        DefaultResizer resizer = new DefaultResizer(lowerBound, upperBound);
        BroadcastRouter broadcastRouter2 = new BroadcastRouter(resizer);
        ActorRef actorBroadcastRouter2 = system.actorOf(new Props(TickerWatcherActor.class).withRouter(broadcastRouter2), "router2");

        ActorRef actor4 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class).withRouter((RouterConfig) broadcastRouter2));
        ActorRef actor5 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class).withRouter((RouterConfig) broadcastRouter2));
        ActorRef actor6 = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class).withRouter((RouterConfig) broadcastRouter2));
```

Right now the Actor "actorBroadcastRouter2" is receiving the message not the intended LimitOrderActor actors 4, 5 and 6. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I believe now what I am looking for is the [Event Bus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/event-bus.html) not the BroadcastRouter

```
   final ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class));
   system.eventStream().subscribe(actor, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Event Bus not the BroadcastRouter:

```
final ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(new Props(LimitOrderActor.class));
system.eventStream().subscribe(actor, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's close this question, I was stumbling around the same problem. This is not the way broadcast routers are working. You create new broadcast routers in `actor4`, `actor5` and `actor6` instead of adding to the existing broadcast router in `actorBroadcastRouter2`.

What you want is really simple in scala with the Listeners trait which is sadly not available when programming Akka with Java:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with Listeners {
  def receive = {
     case yourmessages => gossip("To All my listeners")
  } orElse listenerManagement
}

val myActor = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor])

myActor ! Listen(someActorRef)

myActor ! "pigdog"
```

Have to do your own Java version or use `DistributedPubSubExtension` for a more full-blown thing.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/NEOY9IxRW5I

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Listeners.scala

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html#a-small-example-in-java

Comment: I did my own Java version with the EventStream. The DistributedPubSubExtension is already available in the current 2.1.2 stable release? I believe it's still underdevelopment.

Comment: I didn't use the DistributedPubSubExtension so I cannot tell. It's because it replicates the subscription info to every node, but I rather need to shard the subscription info. AFAIK dead node detection is not available out of the box.